# The name `buildTargets' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

> `EditorWindowIntegration.cs(30,4): error CS0103: The name`buildTargets' does not exist in the current context`

```
public class EbsEditorWindowIntegration : EditorWindow
{
    #region Private Fields
    private List<BuildTargetGroup> Targets;
    private Vector2 ScrollPosition;

    [SerializeField]
    private List<string> Integrations = new List<string>();

#endregion Private Fields

#region Private Methods

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Targets = new List<BuildTargetGroup>();
#if UNITY_5
        Targets.Add(BuildTargetGroup.iOS);
        Targets.Add(BuildTargetGroup.WebGL);
#else
        buildTargets.Add (BuildTargetGroup.iPhone);
#endif
    Targets.Add(BuildTargetGroup.Standalone);
    Targets.Add(BuildTargetGroup.Android);
}
```

Comment: Que linguagem é essa?

Comment: Está parecendo *CSharp* ..

Comment: Unknown até na tag da pergunta